# openGL triange isnt showing

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

[GitHub code](https://github.com/Chu-4hun/Chu-engine/blob/main/main.cpp)

Tried to create my first triangle in openGl but got a black screen.

[image: empty window]

Help find my error

How can i debug such an issue in future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points of your geometry don't define a triangle, but a line:

```
float vertexCoords[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
        -0.0f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f
};
```

all have the same y-coord. Change the last point coords to: `0.5f, 0.5f`.

---

Also you missed to define [VAO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object):

```
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

uint32_t buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexCoords), vertexCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```